# ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid on using custom font

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub changefont(p As Panel)
    Try
        Dim pfc As New PrivateFontCollection()
        pfc.AddFontFile("fonts/droid.ttf")
        For Each ctrl As Control In p.Controls
            ctrl.Font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), 10)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

on each form load i use changefont(panel1)

Comment: On what line? What are the parameter values being used and what is expected?  By the way, why are you creating a new `Font` for every control rather than creating a single `Font` and using it for every control?

Comment: i updated code, see it to understand my problem

Comment: That doesn't make understanding your problem any easier or harder and it doesn't answer any of my questions.